# Possibility Number of Biconnected components greater than number of vertices?

Tags: graph, components, connectivity

This might sound silly but is it possible to have a case where the number of Biconnected components of graph are greater than number of vertices in the graph?

I believe it is not possible and can quickly be validated with small graphs.

Here's a basic logical attempt on why it's not possible
From intuition, if we keep adding edges to a graph in hope that it will increase the number of Biconnected components, it will on contrary decrease the number of components as it will connect more components which were previously not connected.
Leading to, the max number of Biconnected Components can be obtained from a tree like structured graph(because it has min. number of edges while staying connected) (assuming each of the edge is counted as a biconnected component). In a tree the max number of edges can be n-1, where n is the number of vertices and which leads to claim that

"*The max. number of Biconnected Components will be n-1 for any graph*"

Can someone help me validate this proposition, please?

Answer (score 0):

The biconnected components of a graph are connected to each other by vertices called articulation points. When these articulation points are removed from the graph, biconnected components are produced.

If you are referring to the number of biconnected components created by **a single articulation point in a given graph**, then you are correct - it is not possible to have more biconnected components than vertices in a graph.

The minimum number of vertices in a biconnected component is 1. So, if you have a graph with n vertices and remove a single articulation point then you only have n-1 vertices left. From here, the max number of biconnected components is n-1.

A graph like the one below would produce n-1 biconnected components.

[n-1 biconnected components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iteoO.png)

However, there could be multiple articulation points in a graph. Each articulation point, when removed, creates its own biconnected components. If your question is “Is it possible to have more biconnected components than vertices in a graph when accounting for every possible biconnected component that each articulation point can create?”, then the answer would be yes.

For example, the graph below has 6 vertices and articulation points B, C, D, and E. Removing B would create two biconnected components, removing C would create two biconnected components, removing D would create two biconnected components, and removing E would create two biconnected components. This equals 8 possible biconnected components which is greater than 6 (the number of vertices in the graph).

[8 biconnected components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35vzu.png)

Note that there would be 8 **possible** biconnected components. **There cannot be 8 total** biconnected components for a given graph because once one articulation point is removed the graph is already disconnected and you cannot go back and remove more articulation points.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @caldrej, thanks for the answer! The condition you mentioned in your answer is the number of various ways one can have distinct biconnected components from a graph. It is not what I was asking for, which is if we can have n or more biconnected components from a single graph. 
I notice that you have mentioned this already in your last paragraph but the previous lines "f your question is “Is it possible to have more biconnected components than vertices in a graph when accounting for every possible biconnected component....... then the answer would be yes" is confusing gives different impression